# Rails_Admin static select dropdown

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I want to be able to use a static drop down in some of my forms, for example:-

car body type

Hatchback
Saloon
Coupe

any help with this would be great.

Comment: Is body a Model ? Can you edit your post to make it clear ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to do it by putting this in my model;

```
   def body_type_enum 
      ['Hatchback', 'Saloon', 'Estate', 'Convertible', 'MVP', 'Coupe', '4X4'] 
   end
```

Answer (score 0):

The above did not work for me. Here is the working version of my code (Rails 3.1.3, RailsAdmin 0.0.1)

```
[['Item 1'], ['Item 2'], ['Item 3']]
```

If you want the option value to be different you can do like:

```
[['Item 1','item1'], ['Item 2','item2'], ['Item 3','item3']]
```

For dynamic collection, we can write this way:

```
forms = {item1: 'Item 1', item2: 'Item 2', item3: 'Item 3'}
forms.map{|key, val| [val, key]}
```